# C++ code error in my practice code

Tags: c++

Can you please help me out with this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    char str[4];

    A()
    {
        str = "C++";
        cout << "Constructor A" << endl;
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout << str << " is your name" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.display();
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the following errors:

```
**************************Error********** 
StringProg.cpp:9: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member "str" 
StringProg.cpp:9: error: making "str" static StringProg.cpp:9: error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type "char [4]"
StringProg.cpp: In member function "void A::display()":
StringProg.cpp:17: error: "str" was not declared in this scope
**************************
```

Comment: You're lifting above your weight. Try something simple first, like `int main() { char str[4]; str = "C++"; }` and figure out why that doesn't make sense. *Then* go and build something more complex.

Comment: str = "C++'; should be str = "C++";

Comment: Use `std::string`. Char arrays don't play nice.

Comment: @RvdK actually, more like `strncpy(str, "C", sizeof(str));` or maaaaybe `int err = strncpy_s(str, sizeof(str), "C++", 3); if (err!=0) { /*handle error*/ }` ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy))

Comment: This is obviously not "a problem that can no longer be reproduced". 4 close votes cast that way. What is wrong with you people?

Comment: **OP** can we assume the `'`  in `"C++'` was just a typo, and it's not the real source of your issues?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz yes my son. Permission ever-so-gracefully granted

Comment: This 'question' is just a "this does not compile", there is not clear question being asked, no effort shown in trying to work out where that fault might be.

Comment: @thecoshman That comment is just a "I point out this opinion/fact", there is not a clear suggestion being made, no effort shown in trying to improve the situation or shed some light on why this matters.

Comment: How about the things I pointed out should be addressed? Ask a clear question and show some effort in trying to solve it. SO is not a place to pipe compiler errors into.

Comment: Side note... where did you get the notion that you should be using a `char[]` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @thecoshman And comments are not the place to vent about it. The voting buttons are patient. If you wanted to coax the OP, just tell him what could be improved. And perhaps that it needs improving. Perhaps even suggest an edit.

Answer (score 7):

There are quite a few issues with C arrays that prevent you from doing what you want to do.

- String literals have type of `const char[n]` (`n` being their length + 1 for `\0` character). To use them in C Standard Library functions, they decay to `const char*`, which don't carry the size of the string, and in order to find it, the strings need to be traversed (every character being looked at and compared to `\0`)
- As a consequence, array assignment operator would need to be rather nontrivial; this isn't provided by the language, and you have to use library functions like `strcpy` to move the literal into your usable memory. In other words, you can't assign C arrays like other values.
- Arrays function in a very primitive way; they don't have operators for comparison, it's harder to pass them to functions and store in the classes properly.

And so, because of all the above...

#### Prefer `std::string` to `char[]`:

```
class A {
    std::string str;

public:
    // prefer constructor init list
    A() : str("C++") {
        // your line would work, too
        std::cout << "Constructor A" << std::endl;
    }

    void display() const {
        std::cout << str << " is your name" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.display();
    // return 0; is unnecessary
}
```

Some "rules of thumb" (rules of thumbs?): if you need more than one element, start with `vector<>`. Never use C arrays. `string` is *one* element, not an "array of characters".

Comment: You post does not answer what is wrong with the original program.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow And it doesn't have to. By avoiding the complicated, low-level solution, the OP can solve his problem more easily, in an understandable way, and only go back to the primitive concepts if he really wants or needs to. I found it unnecessary to expand too much on the legacy parts of the language that don't get much use in modern C++ anyway.

Comment: He is not asking about other solutions. He is asking why his program does not compile, what is wrong with his program. If the author does not use std;:string it does not mean that his program is wrong.

Comment: Moreover it would be wrong for such a simple program to use class std::string. In fact all what he need is a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow *If the author does not use std;:string it does not mean that his program is wrong* of course; nobody claimed otherwise. That being said, as I already pointed out in another comment thread, the question doesn't mention things you supposedly see in it. As for the string literal pointer... why? This means you have to introduce yet another type of variable for what exactly? A `const std::string` would do as fine, keeping everything its interface brings, like easier use in Standard Library algorithms.

Comment: Vlad's right. On Stack Overflow we take questions about programs, and answer those questions. Suggesting an alternative approach is a nice side-comment, but you're not doing the OP any favours by _ignoring his question entirely_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit prompted by the comments, I've added a better justification of rewording the OP's code into `std::string`.

Comment: The answer is much better now, though you still don't say simply and clearly why it is that the OP's code is broken: that native arrays cannot be copy-assigned. You touch on it but in advanced wording that the OP doesn't have a hope in hell of understanding.

Comment: Yes, the actually problem with the OPs code should be addressed (incorrectly trying to assign the C string), but a more valid answer should provide a **good solution** and that is to use std::string. As has been pointed out, had the OP used C++ concepts and not C concepts (std::string instead of char*) this problem would have been solved. And completely disagree with the notion that a program can be 'too simple' to use good code. By that logic the OP should go back to using assembly, maybe even make them hand wire wrap some ROM to load the program.

Comment: @thecoshman Using std:;string in thius case is a very bad solution. There is no any need to use the whole class std:;string that to output a string literal. OP is learning the language and it is clear enough (except of course you) that he is learning character arrays now and his task is to manage correctly character arrays.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: What is std:;string?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow his question is tagged C++. `char[]` has NO PLACE in C++. It is a horrible, nauseating, fault ridden hold over from C. If you are writing C++ and want to handle strings, use `std::string`. The only time you should touch filthy low level char[] strings is when you have to suffer working with a either a C interface or terrible C++ written by people who are as bad char[] strings. Yes, there most certainly are valid times when you might want to  use a char[], but as a string, never. If you need to send a char[] to some C interface, use std::string::c_str()

Comment: @VladfromMoscow of, and what is this nonsense about 'the whole class'?

Comment: @thecoshman: What's there to say? Your comment was wrong. There are plenty of perfectly valid use cases for C-strings in modern C++. But cargo culting is fun; I get that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Either way, this most certainly is not a valid reason to use C strings. If the OP had clearly stated that they had some reason why they were using them, then yes, suggesting std::string would be stupid, but as it stands, the best way for the OP to fix their problem is avoid C strings.

Comment: @thecoshman: They should use `std::string` here, yes. We should inform them of that, yes. Should we totally avoid actually teaching them what the problem was (and, by extension, just _why_ `std::string` is a safer and more useful tool)? Absolutely not. Fortunately, Bartek has come around on that now.

Comment: It's rather easy, actually: Yes, there's valid use cases for C strings in C++. But, no, you shouldn't use them anyway when you don't know how they work. The OP doesn't, so he shouldn't. Instead he should be pointed at `std::string`. Which this answer does. Hence it's got my vote.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

class A
{
private:
    char str[4];

public:
    A() : str { "C++" }
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor A" << std::endl;
    }

    void display() const
    {
        std::cout << str << " is your name" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    a.display();

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Constructor A
C++ is your name
```

Take into account that arrays do not have the copy assignment operator. Thus this statement in your program

```
str = "C++';
```

even if to update the typo and write

```
str = "C++";
```

is invalid.

You could use standard C function `strcpy` declared in header `<cstring>`. For example

```
    #include <cstring>

    //...

    A()
    {
        std::strcpy( str, "C++" );
        std::cout << "Constructor A" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer to the question. Ignoring the dangerous `strcpy` recommendation!

Comment: Well done @Vlad, you have addressed very directly what was wrong with the OPs attempt at copying a raw C string. But failed at improving the code overall. std::string is absolutely to *right* way to fix this code. Take note, the OP did not specifically ask what was wrong with their string copy, but the code in general. They are clearly learning C++ and as such should be shown how to do things 'correctly'.